# OpenCV: How to copy a NormalBayesClassifier?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am training and testing more classifiers and I want to save just the best of them. I have tried to use an if and `=`

```
// for each train/eval
if (smallestError > errorRate)
{
  best_Classifier = classifier;
}
// end for
best_Classifier.save("name");
```

but it seems that it gives me some null pointer error:

```
OpenCV Error: Null pointer (Null pointer to the written object) in cvWrite, file /home/me/opencv/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp, line 5011
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/me/opencv/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp:5011: error: (-27) Null pointer to the written object in function cvWrite
```

---

**EDIT:**

The code that works, using `std::vector`:

```
std::vector< cv::NormalBayesClassifier> classifiers(10);
int classifierPosition = 0;
double smallestError = 2.;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  // extract vocabulary from X images chosen randomly
  // extract BOW descriptors for the X images used for training
  // extract BOW descriptors for the N-X images used for testing (the ground truth)
  classifiers[i].train(trainingData, labels);
  classifiers[i].predict(evalData, &results);
  double errorRate = (double) cv::countNonZero(groundTruth - results) / evalData.rows;
  if (smallestError > errorRate)
  {
    smallestError = errorRate;
    classifierPosition = i;
  }
}
classifier[classifierPosition].save("name.yaml");
```

If I use `cv::Ptr`, it wont work:

```
cv::Ptr< cv::NormalBayesClassifier> bestClassifier;
double smallestError = 2.;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  // extract vocabulary from X images chosen randomly
  // extract BOW descriptors for the X images used for training
  // extract BOW descriptors for the N-X images used for testing (the ground truth)
  cv::NormalBayesClassifier classifier;
  classifier.train(trainingData, labels);
  classifier.predict(evalData, &results);
  double errorRate = (double) cv::countNonZero(groundTruth - results) / evalData.rows;
  if (smallestError > errorRate)
  {
    smallestError = errorRate;
    bestClassifier = &classifier;
  }
}
bestClassifier->save("name.yaml"); // here it gives me that error
```

Comment: doubtful if you can copy it at all.

Comment: Can you suggest me a way of doing this? I do not want to save many classifiers and then search for the best of those

Comment: maybe have an array of those, and keep the *index* of the best ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

best bet is to use a pointer

one of these should be okay

```
    // opencv shared ptr
    cv::Ptr<cv::NormalBayesClassifier> best_Classifier;
    //or c++11 shared
    shared_ptr<cv::NormalBayesClassifier> best_Classifier;
    //or C raw ptr
    cv::NormalBayesClassifier * best_Classifier;



    if (smallestError > errorRate)
    {
            //raw ptr example 
            best_Classifier = &classifier;
    }
    // end for
    best_Classifier->save("name");
```

although I see nothing wrong with saving them all, or using the index trick @berak

edit write comments, without `std::vector`:

```
    cv::Ptr< cv::NormalBayesClassifier> bestClassifier;
    double smallestError = 2.;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {

        cv::Ptr< cv::NormalBayesClassifier> classifier = new cv::NormalBayesClassifier;
        classifier->train(trainingData, labels);
        classifier->predict(evalData, &results);
        double errorRate = (double) cv::countNonZero(groundTruth - results) / evalData.rows;
        if (smallestError > errorRate)
        {
             smallestError = errorRate;
             bestClassifier = classifier;
      }
   }
   bestClassifier->save("name.yaml"); // no more error
```

Comment: This way I got `OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented () in CvStatModel::write, file /home/me/opencv/modules/ml/src/inner_functions.cpp, line 114
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/me/opencv/modules/ml/src/inner_functions.cpp:114: error: (-213)  in function CvStatModel::write`

Comment: okay, so have you managed to save any NormalBayesClassifier at all?  because that error looks as though it has no definition :/

Comment: In fact if I do `best_Classifier = &classifier;` (for `cv::Ptr`) it gives me that error, why? Shall I make `classifier` a `cv::Ptr`, too?

Comment: not sure, it works over here, maybe post a more complete code.  If you make classifier a pointer also you don't need & before. but if it doesn't work with the raw pointer then the cvPtr probably wont help (unless you deleted the object someplace)

Comment: I have added the code: using `std::vector` and using `cv::Ptr`

Comment: oh, okay so yes, make it cvPtr also, sorry